# Are files downloaded directly in Javascript or through the website?

Tags: javascript

When I want to download a file by making the XmlHttpRequest in Javascript from a seperate server, will the file be downloaded through the website hosting the Javascript page?

For example, I have a web page hosted on server A. The javascript in the web page will download a file from server B. Will the file be downloaded through server A?
The reason for my confusion is due to CORS. I had to put a CORS header in the responses of server B, white-listing server A's domain. So this is confusing me a bit, since Javascript is supposed to client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I want to download a file by making the XmlHttpRequest in Javascript from a seperate server, will the file be downloaded through the website hosting the Javascript page?

No, of course not. The URL doesn't point to that site.

> The reason for my confusion is due to CORS. I had to put a CORS header in the responses of server B, white-listing server A's domain.
>    So this is confusing me a bit, since Javascript is supposed to client-side.

It is.

The browser knows where the page hosting the JavaScript came from.

It knows that you are asking for a file from a different site.

The browser won't let your JavaScript read the file unless the server the file comes from says that the JavaScript on the other site is trusted.